# How can i get a variable using a string in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, variables

Hello I've been wondering this for a while now and it has caused me many problems throughout coding in python. Is there a way that i can get the value of a variable using a string.

e.g

```
a = ['1','2','3']

b = ['4','5','6']

letter = 'a'
print(letter)
```

desired output would be the `a` list: `['1','2','3']`

Comment: This is a *terrible* code smell. What you need is a dictionary.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The non-recommended way is `print(eval('a'))`

Comment: [Never, ever do this](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.cl/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html). Use a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put a in quotation marks , because it will become a string not a variable.
Try to remove the quotation marks

```
a =[“1”,“2”]
letter = a
print(letter)
```

Comment: @GauravRai yeah，because you set a to a list , now a is a variable, if you put in-between quotation marks, it will become a quote, which means it will no longer be a variable that contain the list , if you just remove the quotations it will work.